# Firefox vs Chrome: how to open new tabs in foreground or background with same meta keys?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, shortcut, firefox, web-browser

## The Request

How can I make the same meta keys between Firefox and Chrome **do the same thing**?

In my macOS, currently in my environment (`<click>` = `"mouse left click on weblink"`), the following "open new weblink in new tab" keyboard behavior is inconsistent between Firefox and Chrome.

### Chrome

- open new-web-page tab in **foreground**: `cmd-shift-<click>`
- open new-web-page tab in *background*: `cmd-<click>`

### Firefox

- open new-web-page tab in **foreground**: `cmd-<click>`
- open new-web-page tab in *background*: `cmd-shift-<click>`

It matters less which keyboard-shorcut-plus-click does which thing (although I'd prefer the `cmd-<click>` opens in _background); I at least want the behavior to be *consistent* between these 2 web-browsing apps.

### My current versions

```
macos: 10.14.6
firefox: 76.0.1 (64-bit)
chrome: Version 81.0.4044.92 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

## Failed (thus far) solutions

I've thus far been unable to get the following solutions to help/work:

- https://github.com/mikecrittenden/shortkeys/wiki/How-To-Use-Shortkeys
- https://superuser.com/a/1260437/98033

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, those are builtin shortcuts are hard coded and can’t be changed.   Just doing some spot checking the shortcuts seem to line up cross platform with the following conventions `Ctrl` = `Cmd`, `Opt` = `Alt` Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Employing the following Firefox preferences settings achieved what I wanted. In particular: the annotation highlights the setting I unchecked that made things work on my system.

[image: macOS Firefox preferences]